# Cannot Run Fork, unwanted number of processes are forked

Tags: perl, fork

I am having an issue with Fork in Perl. I want to execute 10 Fork Processes at a go from one single script all 10 Child (Forked) processes will do the same thing (Copy files from one place to another).

When I execute this code, my OS Hangs and when I actually check there are hell lot of processes which are forked at a time.

Here is my Code:

```
while ($callCount <= $totalCalls) {
 for (1..$TotalProcessToFork) {
         print "Call -> $callCount";
         if($pid = fork) {
             #in Parent Process
             print " :: PID -> $pid\n";
             push(@list_of_pid, $pid);
         } else {
             #in Child Process
             `touch $callCount`;
         }
         $callCount++;
     }
 }
```

Now when I execute this code, there are around 1000 child processed which are executed.

Can any one tell me what wrong I am doing here.

Answer (score 4):

The children fork, too. You need to exit the loop one way or another in the child case. A common pattern is to fork and exec, or you could just say `last`.

Comment: Ok, I modified it to: "exec ('touch', $callCount) or die $!;", but now my main program exits when fork is complete. There are more operations to do after this process is complete, but my main program exits here.

Comment: @user1065000, that's because you never wait for your children to end. See `wait` and `waitpid`.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because when you fork a process, it creates two processes. Lets call them `a1` and `a2`. Now `a1` is the parent and `a2` is the child, so when `a2` is executed, it creates `b1` and `b2`. When these all are executed, they also create new processes recursively.

Comment: Hemant Metalia, I noticed your answer was downvoted. This most likely because of the bad quality of your diction. I have edited to improve it. – For future answers, please use the correct punctuation and orthography. Take the time to formulate proper sentences to express what you want to say, do not just write down a stream-of-conciousness.

Comment: Thank you daxim sorry for my bad english i will take care for next time.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at [`Parallel::ForkManager`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Parallel%3a%3aForkManager), which will probably make your life easier.

Also, don't use external Linux `touch` command; it's better to use [`File::Touch`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aTouch).

Answer (score 0):

Independent of Perl: Learn how fork works!

In your loop the first process being forked continues to execute the loop `` $TotalProcessToFork -1`times, the second process being forked by the original parent will execute the loop`$TotalProcessToFork -2` times, and so on...

*In addition* the first child forked by the first child will *also* execute the loop `$TotalProcessToFork -3` times.

Maybe try this code:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $TotalProcessToFork = 3;

for (1..$TotalProcessToFork) {
    print "PID $$ processes $_\n";
    if ((my $pid = fork) > 0) {
        print "parent $$ processing $_ created PID $pid\n";
    } else {
        print "child $$ processes $_\n";
    }
}
```

When I ran it, I got this output:

```text
PID 13415 processes 1
parent 13415 processing 1 created PID 13416
PID 13415 processes 2
child 13416 processes 1
parent 13415 processing 2 created PID 13417
PID 13415 processes 3
PID 13416 processes 2
parent 13415 processing 3 created PID 13418
parent 13416 processing 2 created PID 13419
PID 13416 processes 3
PID 13417 processes 3
parent 13416 processing 3 created PID 13420
parent 13417 processing 3 created PID 13421
child 13420 processes 3
child 13418 processes 3
child 13421 processes 3
child 13419 processes 2
PID 13419 processes 3
child 13422 processes 3
parent 13419 processing 3 created PID 13422
```